# Rails - Ruby 3.1.1 will not load on CentOS but okay on OSX

Tags: ruby-on-rails, centos, precompile

I have a rails app that runs fine on my development iMac (Ventura). I pushed to production CentOS7. It bundled up fine but when trying to to assets precompile I get the error below. I have tried, removing lock file and re-bundling, updating bundler, did gem update and did yum update on server. I get the following when doing rake assets:clean precompile and I see similar error in apache log as well. I am running rails 7.0.4.2 and ruby 3.1.1.  I need some guidance on how to resolve.

```
 rake assets:clean precompile
rake aborted!
LoadError: cannot load such file -- Version
<internal:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
<internal:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.1/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.6/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:38:in `require'
/admin/bin/rails/catering_bk/config/initializers/active_admin.rb:290:in `block in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.1/gems/activeadmin-2.13.1/lib/active_admin.rb:68:in `setup'
/admin/bin/rails/catering_bk/config/initializers/active_admin.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.1/gems/railties-7.0.4.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:667:in `load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.1/gems/railties-7.0.4.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:667:in `block in load_config_initializer'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.1/gems/activesupport-7.0.4.2/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:208:in `instrument'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.1/gems/railties-7.0.4.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:666:in `load_config_initializer'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.1/gems/railties-7.0.4.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:620:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.1/gems/railties-7.0.4.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:619:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.1/gems/railties-7.0.4.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:619:in `block in <class:Engine>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.1/gems/railties-7.0.4.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.1/gems/railties-7.0.4.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.1/gems/railties-7.0.4.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.1/gems/railties-7.0.4.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.1/gems/railties-7.0.4.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `tsort_each_child'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.1/gems/railties-7.0.4.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.1/gems/railties-7.0.4.2/lib/rails/application.rb:372:in `initialize!'
/admin/bin/rails/catering_bk/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
<internal:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
<internal:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.1/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.6/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:38:in `require'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.1/gems/railties-7.0.4.2/lib/rails/application.rb:348:in `require_environment!'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.1/gems/railties-7.0.4.2/lib/rails/application.rb:511:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.1/gems/sprockets-rails-3.4.2/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:61:in `block (2 levels) in define'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:22:in `eval'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:22:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

As noted above. I tried

- Remove lock file and bundle again.
- gem update
- yum update

Also to note this is also an older app that was upgraded to be in compliance with Veracode. It works perfectly on OSX, so the issue must be within CentOS.

Comment: what happens if you run `bundle exec gem env` on your production environment?

Comment: The output from that seems fine. all versions and paths seem to be as they should.    RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 3.4.6
  - RUBY VERSION: 3.1.1 (2022-02-18 patchlevel 18) [x86_64-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.1
  - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /root/.gem/ruby/3.1.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.1/bin/ruby
  - GIT EXECUTABLE: /bin/git
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.1/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /root/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.1/etc

Comment: It's not completely clear from your question which of the commands you ran locally and which on your production server. You mention deleting the lockfile and running bundle, did you do that locally and then commit the new lockfile to version control? Also, `gem update` is not relevant, you should only be changing gem versions using bundler. Unless you mean `gem update --system`, which affects the infrastructure gems and not your application. If you do mean that you ran `gem update --system` I suggest updating your question with the exact commands you typed in each context.